# Java: How to write: <a href="url">Click Here</a> in BufferedWriter?

Tags: html, filewriter, bufferedwriter

```
fileWriter = new FileWriter(PathBrowser.filepath+"/"+"index.html");
        fwrite = new BufferedWriter(fileWriter);
        fwrite.write("<html>");
        fwrite.write("<h1>HTML TEST</h1>");
        //fwrite.write("<a href="http://www.yahoo.com">here</a>");
        fwrite.write("</html>");
```

So how is it possible for me to write this: Click Here in the index.html file? I can't seem to figure this out.
I have tried many things so far, for example:
("\"\"");
Any help would be much appreciated!
Thank you in advance.

Comment: I'd imagine: `fwrite.write("<a href=\"http://www.yahoo.com\">here</a>");` - But what language is that?  C#? Java?

Comment: Wrap the html attribute values in single quotes instead?

Comment: Thank you Mike Christensen, that was what I was looking for :) Silly of me of not trying it that way! Thank you again!